# How do I Maximize over a Cuboid region?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions

So, I want to, say, find a maximum value of $|x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3-x_2x_4|$ in a unit cube in 4D; how do I do that?

I've tried

`NMaximize[Abs[a*c + a*d + b*c - b*d], {a, b, c, d } in Cuboid[{0, 0, 0, 0}]]`,

but it said that

`a in Cuboid[{0,0,0,0}] is not a valid variable`;

I also tried doing

`Maximize[Abs[a* c + b* c + a *d - b* d], {{a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, {d, 0, 1}} ]`,

but did not prevail as well.

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NMaximize[
 Abs[a*c + a*d + b*c - b*d], {a, b, c, d} \[Element] 
  Cuboid[{0, 0, 0, 0}]]
```

(*
{2., {a -> 1., b -> 1., c -> 1., d -> 1.}}
*)

Comment: Oh, so _that's_ how you write $\in$... Thanks!

Comment: @Akiiino. Alternatively, hit the escape button, type `elem`, and hit the escape button again.

Comment: @Akiiino... gosh, so not even an upvote?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork sort of waiting for the site to allow me to accept the answer... But yeah, definitely no upvote now